# stop connecting points in pandas time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, series

I have some data in a pandas series and when I type

```
 mydata.head()
```

I get:

```
                       BPM
timestamp   
2015-04-07 02:24:00    96.0
2015-04-07 02:24:00    96.0
2015-04-07 02:24:00    95.0
2015-04-07 02:24:00    95.0
2015-04-07 02:24:00    95.0
```

Also, when using

```
 mydata.info()
```

I get:

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 DatetimeIndex: 33596 entries, 2015-04-07 02:24:00 to 2015-07-15 14:23:50
 Data columns (total 1 columns):
 BPM    33596 non-null float64
 dtypes: float64(1)
 memory usage: 524.9 KB
```

When I go to plot using

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

 fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
 ax.plot(mydata)
```

[image: time series plot with points connected]

I just get a complete mess, it's like it's joining lots of points together that should not be joined together.

How can I sort this out to display as a proper time series plot?

Comment: have you tried mydata.plot('.')

Comment: Is your data sorted by date?

Comment: You may need to specify the format of the dates when you parse a string column to a date column (e.g. pd.todatetime(df['column'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S) ) before setting this column as the index. Maybe days have switched with months.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
mydata.plot(style="o")
```

and you should get a Pandas plot without lines connecting the points.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell `matplotlib` to plot markers instead of lines. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(my data, '+')
```

If you prefer another marker, you can change it ([see this link](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/api/markers_api.html)).

You can also plot directly from `pandas`:

```
mydata.plot('+')
```

If you really want the lines, you need to sort your data before plotting it.